# Finding period from differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a differential equation
$y''+ky=0$, is it possible to find the period of $y$ without actually solving the ODE? The solution is $y=y_0\cos(\sqrt {k} t)$ for the initial condition $y(0)=y_0 
 ;\ y'(0)=0$ which has period $2\pi k^{-1/2}$. How could one compute the period directly from the ODE or isn't it possible?

Comment: I don't understand - didn't you *just* give an expression for the period? Why try to find it this other way?

Comment: look at the imaginary part of the roots of the characteristic equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characteristic equation: $r^2+k=0$.

Solutions are $\pm i\sqrt{k}$ which signals harmonic solutions.

Imaginary coefficient is the period -- $\sqrt{k}$.